# Performing calculations based on specific row of DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to perform a calculation on each row in a df based on the values of another row in the df, and then add the output as a score in a new column...

So, for example, I have:

```
League DefDuels AerialDuels PPDA
Albania  10        4.         8
Scotland 11        5.         9
England  12        6.         10
```

And I want to multiply the value of DefDuels in England by DefDuels in Albania, then add the answer as a new column, but then also perform this operation for England and Scotland (England will remain constant throughout the calculations in the df).

I hope this makes sense, apologies if not, this is my firs posting on here.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a lambda function to calculate the new column's value

```
import pandas as pd


df_d = {'League': ['Albania', 'Scotland', 'England'], 'DefDuels':[10,11,12], 'AerialDuels': [4., 5., 6.]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_d)


England_row = df.loc[df['League']=='England']

England_value = England_row['DefDuels'].values[0]

df['New Column'] = df['DefDuels'].apply(lambda x:  England_value * x )

df.loc[2,'New Column'] = 'N/A'

print(df)
```

returns

```
    League  DefDuels  AerialDuels New Column
0   Albania        10          4.0        120
1  Scotland        11          5.0        132
2   England        12          6.0        N/A
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to be working. It isn't returning a single value in the 'New column'. Seems to be adding a whole DF into the column.

Comment: Sorry! I have updated the code to select the specific value and then do the lambda function.

Comment: That's great, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: If you found the answer sufficient be sure to up vote it and mark the question as solved.